How to make API calls in a given order
I can't make calls in correct order. I was trying to reproduce given scenario, but failed to recreate the correct order of requests in k6. I think it's a mix of Promise.All with synchronous calls, but yet didn't go well.
Now it's just a straightforward list of calls:
group('Map', function () {
    group('Open Map with Given Build and Level', function () {
      
      app.getUserType(authToken, 23);
      app.projectFieldsPage.getKPIsIDByName(authToken, 23);
      app.getUser(authToken);
      app.getProjectInfo(authToken,23)
      app.dashboardPage.getProjectShort(authToken, 23);
      app.projectFieldsPage.getSelectControlKPIs(authToken, 23);
      app.getBuildsInfoShort(authToken, 23, 142);
      app.globalSettingsPage.getProjectSettings(authToken, 23);
      app.getLevelsInfoShort(authToken, 23, 142, 471);     
      app.layoutsPage.getLayoutsWithPermissions(authToken, 23);
    });
    sleep(1);

I want a, b, c requests to start at the same time, but display a response as soon as it will end not waiting for b and c to end and not blocking their start.

Please show us the code you're working with and describe the desired behavior. We can't do anything with your dev tools waterfall diagram.

Thank you for editing your code in, but you still need to tell us what you're trying to do. Questions must be self-contained; we're not going to go off-site to understand the "given scenario". Please read [ask].

In javascript, if you want to make multiple fetch requests in order, you have to use the await keyword, since by default, the fetch requests are asynchronous.
const requests = ["/api/user", "/api/business/1", "/api/version"]

let responses = []
(async function() {
    for (const request of requests) {
        responses.push(await fetch(request));
    }

    console.log(responses);
})()

In this example, we have an array of endpoints you want to make a request to and an array of responses. Then, we have an IIFE (Immediately invoked function expression) to be able to use the await keyword at the top level. In this function, we loop over all the endpoints and make a request to each one using fetch and then store that response in the responses array, which we then print out.
You can of course add error handling, custom headers and many more options, but this should give you a general idea of how to execute requests in order.

how to handle situation if I want a,b,c requests to start at the same time, but display a response as soon as it will end not waiting for b and c to end and not blocking their start

then you could just fetch all of them and use callbacks with .then

can you please write generic function describing actions?

Is it like  fetch(b); fetch(c); fetch(a).then(r=>console.log(r))?

You could do that, but that would discard the result of b and c

Probably, I just don't quite get nature of promises. if I say a = await fetch(a) - I make code to wait for it? and if i want to move forward not waitng for resolving and fire next requests?

Then you should probably go read some stuff or watch some videos to learn about the topic. Better than just getting the code

I did(( After reading some stuff and chatGpt didn't work out hoped community will help.
